# c # MVC Share error on Facebook page ( OAuthException #200 )

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, model-view-controller

Although I have full authority, error is error authority:

> (OAuthException - #200) (#200) Requires either publish_to_groups permission and app being installed in the group, or manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with sufficient administrative permission

Facebook Developer below is my display image and
screenshot of my code.

---

App ID  10525 : makineadresi

Type:   User

App-Scoped User ID

Learn More

10214 : Makine Adresi

User last installed this app via: API N/A

Issued: 159756 (about a week ago)

Expires:    Never

Data Access Expires:    Never

Valid:  True

Origin: Unknown

Scopes: user_events, email, manage_pages, pages_manage_cta, pages_manage_instant_articles, pages_show_list, publish_pages, business_management, publish_to_groups, groups_access_member_info, public_profile

---

```
string FBPub_ClientId = "4714088892553";
string FBPub_ClientSecret = "80749ba484de42952e928677";

dynamic FacebookPost = new ExpandoObject();


FacebookPost.link = "http://makineadresi.com/tr/80-LiK-Alman-Borwerk-1215";
FacebookPost.caption = "header";
FacebookPost.message = "sub information";

try
{
    FacebookClient appp = new FacebookClient("EAABcHPvQGZBUBAA1E3gxwHpp2Ap0uBTXwZAa7ZAalHl3gf0xBhOpVHCzwZDZD");
    appp.AppId = FBPub_ClientId;
    appp.AppSecret = FBPub_ClientSecret;
    var postId = appp.Post("/13289/feed", FacebookPost);
    return postId[0];
}
```

---

Could you please help ?

All my links in my code are correct. The explanations are modified shapes.

Comment: I've realized now. thanks

Comment: What are you trying to post to - a user profile? That is not possible any more via API, the permission necessary for that has been removed a while ago.

Comment: description and photo. what can i do

Comment: Is that supposed to answer the question I asked you somehow …?

Comment: I want to make a share on the page that I created, not to the user profile.

Comment: Then you need to use a page access token, and not a user token as you are doing right now.

Comment: I do not understand. more clearly tell.

Comment: I have read and applied them before. however, I cannot get rid of 200 errors. Please don't engage if you don't know anything.

Comment: Please don’t give me that kind of attitude, just because you can’t manage to get things done correctly, thank you. _“I have read and applied them before.”_ - the debug output(?) you showed above clearly says “Type: User”, so that is _not_ a page access token. How to get one … explained in docs.

Comment: Sorry for my reaction. I don't think that this has anything to do with the user.

Comment: I did not say it had anything to do with _the user_, but with the _type of token_ you are using. You need to use a page access token to post _as_ a page. Using a user token would only have posted onto the visitors section of the page, _as_ the user. (_Would have_, because as said, posting as a user is not possible any more.)

Comment: As you can see in my code page id is used as the token.                                 var postId = appp.Post("/13289/feed", FacebookPost);

Comment: I am talking about the _access token_ used to make the API call, not the page _id_. An object id, and an access token are two very different things.

Comment: We are currently moving away from the problem. The main problem is that all the tokens and authorizations are all true while I still get the 200 error.

Comment: No, the problem is that you are using the wrong kind of token.

Comment: I would get errors in get requests if the token was wrong. I get the right answers when my request is (get  )

Comment: _“I get the right answers when my request is (get )”_ - that’s because your page admin user is allowed to _read_ posts with their user token. You are trying to _create_ a post here however, and that, again, how many more times, *sigh*, needs a page access token.

Comment: Thank you I found Access Token which is necessary.
I'll do the description below

Answer (score 0):

Access Token which is incorrect. The following steps of Access Token can be accessed correctly.

1. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ click url.
2. where( me?fields=id,name) is written (me/accounts) in summer.
3. Use the access token located under the data.